# SQL Server 2000: "subquery returned more than one value" on an update statement

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do a simple update. I've done this kind of thing thousands of times.

```
update articles
set department = 60
where type = 'Top Story'
```

Today I get a strange error.

> Describe Error: Failed to retrieve
>   execution plan: Subquery returned more
>   than 1 value. This is not permitted
>   when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=
>   , >, >= or when the subquery is used
>   as an expression.
>
> Warnings: --->     W (1): The
>   statement has been terminated.
>             <---
>
> 1559 record(s) affected

There is no subquery in the update statement. What's going on?

Comment: Doesn't make sense.  You get that error only executing the code you pasted above?

Comment: Using "IN" can give you performance headaches down the road. I'd change that IN you say you added with an "EXISTS", and change the subquery so it's a correlated subquery. At least with Oracle and SQLServer, these work faster.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most likely there is a trigger on the table, and the error is occurring in the trigger, not in your actual SQL statement.

I would further bet that the trigger assumes the insert or delete special tables will only ever have a single row (which is in fact not the case in mass updates, like the one you're executing), causing the problem.

Comment: Nice catch! The table has an update trigger containing this clause: "where articleID = (select articleID from INSERTED)"

I changed the "=" to "in" and it worked as expected.

Comment: Wow. I ran across this last week and it drove me nuts. Come to find out, the guy before me slapped triggers in and didn't tell anyone. Thanks much!