# updating one table to another sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

ok..i'm sure i'm having a brain fart moment..but for some reason i cant get this update to work. I have 2 tables, i'm pretty much trying to copy info from 8 columns to 8 columns in another table. ..
this is what i have so far

```
update a
set a.denialcharge_cost = b.denial_cost
    , a.epd_cost = b.early_default_payment
    , a.expeditecharge_cost = b.expeditecharge
    , a.duediligence_cost = b.duediligence
    , a.deskreview_cost = b.deskreview
    , a.servicing_cost = b.servicingcharge
    , a.mers_cost = b.merscharge
    , a.qcplans_cost = b.qcplans
from orderheader a 
inner join clients b
on a.prnt_id = b.id
```

i get the error

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateOrderHeader, Line 13
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

i have x number of clients in clients..and y number of orders in orderheader..every order can have 1 client..every client can have multiple orders...prnt_id in orderheader has the id in the clients table....any help would be appreciated... i'm trying to copy denial_cost, early_default_payment, expeditecharge, duediligence, deskreview, servicingcharge, merscharge, qcplans
from clients to orderheader

Comment: could it be because you don't have a where clause ?

Comment: please post the database system you use. (as tag)

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, you're trying to update every single order header with information from the client. This begs the question, why do this at all? Why not just relate the order header to the client info and grab the info from the client table? You seem to be working against the relational model here.

Comment: we have it relating to client table atm, problem is, when we change the clients rates, it updates ALL the old invoices..so it looks like they owe us money, or we owe them,.. (i didnt build this), so the idea is that all future invoices would, once they were created,  save their initial price in orderheader, instead of being called from client

Comment: It just dawned on me ... is this your initial update and from here everything will change? You still need some further refinement to get to a 1:1

Comment: what does `select id, count(id) from clients group by id having count(id) > 1` give you?

Comment: nothing..haha..i tried this earlier as well..same for orderheader...that's why i came here

Comment: Triggers on the table? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149124/sql-server-2000-subquery-returned-more-than-one-value-on-an-update-statement

Comment: good call, checked earlier, didnt see any, but didnt check inside table, only checked main triggers,..yea there is one

Comment: go ahead and answer it @swasheck ..i disabled it, did my update, re-enabled..thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149124/sql-server-2000-subquery-returned-more-than-one-value-on-an-update-statement) to a previous question, and all of the other troubleshooting that we did, it appears as though you have a trigger getting in the way somewhere. Try disabling it and running the update.

Answer (score 0):

SOMETHING like that should work (with formatting)

```
update orderheader
set denialcharge_cost = b.denial_cost, 
    epd_cost = b.early_default_payment,
    expeditecharge_cost = b.expeditecharge,
    duediligence_cost = b.duediligence,
    deskreview_cost = b.deskreview, 
    servicing_cost = b.servicingcharge,
    mers_cost = b.merscharge, 
    qcplans_cost = b.qcplans
from clients b 
where orderheader.prnt_id = clients.id
```

Comment: this won't work..it's basically the same thing i have in a dif format

Comment: what do you mean not working, are you getting error ?
or the result doesn't met what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand of the error, you are trying do fetch only one result, somewhere and the subquery returns more than a field.

like

select (select * from bb) as count from cc gives an error

because the subquery returns more than a field from the nested query

Comment: yea, i'm trying to have only one result.. well for each column.. but yea

Comment: i tried breaking it out, and update each one with a select, selecting the column i needed..same error..so i added select top 1..same error